# Cannot get PHP variable using isset

Tags: php, xampp

I'm new to PHP and can't get the following code to work:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db_connect.php');


//get the page id
if(isset($_SESSION['logged-in'])&&isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $login = true;
} else {
    $login = false;
}

//check to see if the post_id and the forum_id is set and is a numeric value
if(isset($_GET['pid'])&&is_numeric($_GET['pid'])&&isset($_GET['id'])&&is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];    
} else {
    die("Error");
}
echo $pid;
?>
```

When I run this code, my screen just shows "Error".  I've done a few tests, and it looks like the isset  and/or the is_numeric property isn't working.  I'm using PHP(5.5.1) and MySQL via XAMPP(1.8.3-0).  I'm really not understanding why there's a problem, and I'm assuming that it has something to do with mysql.  What am I missing?? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling your code? What should `pid` and `id` be?

Comment: What tests did you do?

Comment: $pid isn't declared in the scope (in the line: echo $pid) or do you use it somewhere above?

Comment: @alexvii - it's defined in the first branch of the `if` statement.

Comment: Code probably works,now the fact that it doesn't do what you want it to do is another matter.

Comment: Code has no PHP errors as you're getting the else die and seeing error on screen. echo out your vars, or look in the URL as you're using GET, you can see if they're set, likely one isn't or isn't numeric or something.

Comment: @andrewsi but doesn't the scope close after the if and then the reference to pid is gone?

Comment: @alexvii - PHP has a single scope for variables, until you get to functions, which have their own local scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @andrewsi, pid and id refer to post_id and forum_id respectively(I'm creating a forum, and database connection via db_connect.php).

Comment: @Cfreak, I actually had a lot of other code that I had to gradually comment out to pinpoint the error to the section of code above.

Comment: @user2680503 - are you passing them into this code with `$_GET`?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to get your code working all by itself but I'm sure you'll find this trick very useful now and into the future. Change the line which reads: `die("Error");` to read `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_GET); echo '</pre>';`. This will print the entire $_GET array out and allow you to get a better picture of whats going on.

Also, is_numeric() is not going to be good enough here. Try adding this function to your code:

```
function isInteger($input){ return(ctype_digit(strval($input))); }
```

The replace each call to is_numeric() with this new function. is_numeric() will return true for input such as '1.25'. I doubt you're using floating point numbers for your ID fields ;)

Comment: I tried your echo statement and got the following:  `code`("Array
(
    [id] => first thread in forum
) )

Comment: I'm guess that since you posted this here it means you are having trouble interpreting that? What that is saying is that $_GET is an array and it contains 1 item with the key 'id'. 'id' is set to 'first thread in forum'. By looking at your code I'd say that is NOT what you were wanting. Try changing the last part of your URL to read `?id=10` instead of `?id=first%20thread%20in%20forum`. A string will not do here.